# minted FanyVerb Error \end{minted}

Tags: latex, pygments

I have installed MiKTeX 2.9 and Python 3.6.4 on Windows 10. The directory `..\Python36` and `..\Python36\Scripts` are added to the Path Variable. I have also installed pygments via `pip install pygments` and I have also added `-shell-escape` to the TexStudio.

When I compile the .tex file I get the error

```
FancyVerb Error:. \end{minted}
```

Another computer can run the Files without any problems. Does anybody know what I missed?

Answer (score 1):

When I used texlive 2018, I got the same problem. But when I uninstalled texlive 2018 and reinstalled **texlive 2017**, and have python 2.7.13 installed and added the Scripts path to my environment variables, then I compiled without any error!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by moving the minted block to outside the itemize block it was in.